# XAMPP composer PHP Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found

Tags: xampp, composer-php

i'm trying to install ZendFramework 2 and composer (to deal with dependencies) on open suze. My local server is XAMPP. phpinfo() shows Phar enabled but trying a 
    php composer.phar self-update
or even php composer.phar install 
only results in the same error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phar' not found in ..path/to/zendFWApplication.

I'm kinda lost here... any help would be great.
Thank's

Comment: are you sure the `php.ini` is used for both the web interface as the command interface?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was wright but actually not the point: in Phar documentation on www.php.net, it's mentioned that binary package of the phar extension for open size are available ... somewhere... which means it's not installed by default.. so i've looked for it on Open Suze download page and found it .. cool  ! Everything works fine !
Anyway thank's for having answered so quicky.

Comment: I am having the same issue, could you please add more details to your answer?